# Why the decimals places are truncated when creating a Series from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas

I have created a function that does many things. I need it to display two series that are created starting from a list. The problem is that while one of them is displayed correctly, the other one is like "truncated" in the decimals places. But the arrays on which these two series are based are identical. Only the numerical values in them changes.

```
beta_list = np.array(beta_list) # first array
delta_beta = np.array(pippo) #second array

magica1 = pd.Series(beta_list, index=indexer_array) # first series 
magica = pd.Series(delta_beta, index=indexer_array_delta) #second series

return magica, magica1, delta_beta, beta_list
```

When I call the function:

```
PROVA(XRP, BTC,0.25)


(125    9.827752e-06
 243    1.924225e-06
 273    1.616558e-07
 dtype: float64, 0     -0.000001
 125    0.000011
 176   -0.000011
 243    0.000013
 261   -0.000013
 273    0.000013
 dtype: float64, array([9.82775193e-06, 1.92422467e-06, 1.61655820e-07]), array([-1.15469635e-06,  1.09824483e-05, -1.10016071e-05,  1.29258318e-05,
        -1.30224291e-05,  1.31840849e-05]))
```

This is what i get. I can't understand why one array keep the same format and the other one doesn't

Comment: The values are always the same, but way the are displayed depends on the values in the Series. E.g. a series containing 0.1 wouldn't be shown as 0.1000000 unless there's a value requiring much higher precision in the same Series, like 0.0000001

Comment: I know that the values are the same. But they do require higher precision, as you can see in the corresponding array. My question was: Why does python treat an array in a way and another one in a different way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values greater than 1E-5 are displayed as float by default. Below this treshold the default format is scientific format. You can set the precision by calling the following instruction before printing the series :

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:12.5e}'.format
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the explanation. It works just fine

Comment: now also greater number are displayed like that (4.34471e+02). How to set to get back to how it was?

Comment: Change the format again as needed (same instructions). Something like `'{:12.4f}'.format` should work in this case.